# How do I iterate through an object and assign the values (colors) to each div being created

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, javascript-objects, nested-for-loop

I am trying to use the data object which I have created to then output the name into a html div, and then styling that text to be the color which is also stored in the data. I have managed to output the text into the divs, however I would prefer to add classnames. And it seems to just add the red to every single div, which is not what I was looking for.

So the desired output would be:

halfords *red text*
microsoft *green text*
posca *blue text*

I would really appreciate the help, bit of a noob over here!

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#slider-container");

const data = [
  { name: "halfords", color: "red", logo: "" },
  { name: "microsoft", color: "green", logo: "" },
  { name: "posca", color: "blue", logo: "" }
];

// Iterate through object and adding colours to <div>'s
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (const iterator of data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    divs[i].style.color = data[i].color;
  }
}

// Iterating through object and outputting into <div>'s
function createMenuItem(name) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = name;
  return div;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createMenuItem(data[i].name));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="slider-container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some suggestions, you don't need to loop over `data`. Also, it seems you are selecting all divs, including `slide-container`. You could add a class to your divs inside `createMenuItem` instead, and then select only them. Here's how you can do it.

```
const container = document.querySelector("#slider-container");

const data = [
  { name: "halfords", color: "red", logo: "" },
  { name: "microsoft", color: "green", logo: "" },
  { name: "posca", color: "blue", logo: "" },
];

// Iterate through object and adding colours to <div>'s

// Iterating through object and outputting into <div>'s
function createMenuItem(name) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = name;
  div.classList.add("item");
  return div;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createMenuItem(data[i].name));
  }

  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    divs[i].style.color = data[i].color;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

well, the reason you're getting the described effect is that you're effectively iterating over ALL of your divs for *each* of the data items ...

why don't you add a `color` argument to your `createMenuItem` function and assign the style *once*, when each menu item is created?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, thanks for the help! I added color in as a parameter and it worked!! :))

```js
// Object storing values
const data = [
  { name: "Halfords", color: "orange", logo: "" },
  { name: "Microsoft", color: "green", logo: "" },
  { name: "Posca", color: "blue", logo: "" },
];
// Iterating through object and outputting into <div>'s
function createMenuItem(name, color, logo) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = name;
  div.style.color = color;
  div.classList.add("item");
  return div;
}
// Outputting the data into divs using the create item function
const container = document.querySelector("#slider-container");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createMenuItem(data[i].name, data[i].color));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="slider-container"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

only small update :)

```js
// Iterating through object and outputting into <div>'s
function createMenuItem(preperties) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = preperties.name;
div.style.color =  preperties.color
  return div;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createMenuItem(data[i]));
  }
});
```